# SELECT INTO Oracle SQL table from MySQL table with SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select

Getting ready to get rid of a MySQL database and switch to Oracle SQL.  I am using Oracle SQL Developer.  Need to get the records from a MySQL table and populate its corresponding table in SQL.

I was able to establish a Database connection in SQL Developer to the MySQL database. I checked the connection by doing a simple SELECT * from the table to make sure it returned all the records.

However, the new Oracle SQL table has quite a few changes - the names in the MySQL table all had a "tn" prefix, ie tnStore, tnConfigDate, etc.  The SQL table gets rid of that prefix.  That is issue #1.

There will also be several new columns in the new table.  That data will be added later from elsewhere.  And the data will not be in the same order as the MySQL table.

How do a write up a SELECT INTO statement in SQL Developer to populate the SQL table with the data from the MySQL table and correlate the corresponding columns while leaving new fields blank for now?

Comment: I was able to copy the MySQL table from the MySQL Server to Oracle using SQL Developer. Here is the statement I was then able to write and use:

`INSERT INTO TINTER_MASTER 
(STORENBR, MODELNBR, SERIALNBR, ORIGINITDATE, LASTCONFIGDATE, LASTPURGEDATE, 
CLRNTSYSID, PCMODEL, PCSERIALNBR, PCMACID,PCINITDATE)
SELECT 
TNSTORE, TNMODEL, TNSERIALNBR, TNORIGINITDATE, TNINITDATE, TNLASTNETWORKDATE,
TNCLRNTSYS, TNPCMODEL, TNPCSERIALNBR, TNPCMACID, TNPCINITDATE
FROM TINTERSX;`

But can I write that statement to do the INSERT from the MySQL Server to the table on the Oracle Server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way by programming but not sure how to make it in single query:

I hope we need to use data dictionary tables in oracle `all_tab_columns` and I am not sure in Mysql ( like similar table)

1. Get the column name from Mysql table by taking out prefix "tn" and
   compare the column name with SQL table. (possible use an cusrsor)
2. If matched build SQL statement for `SELECT INTO` statement and blank
   for new fields possibly in a loop.
3. Once done for all columns , execute that statement

Answer (score 0):

Consider migrating the existing MySQL tables as-is straight to Oracle using SQL Developer. Then move/refactor the data around to your new-tables with desired column definitions using INSERT as SELECTs.

Could be considerably faster, plus once the 'raw' data is there, you can do your work over and over again, until you get it just right.

Note you can also simply drag-and-drop to move a MySQL table from it's connection to an existing Oracle database connection to move the table over (DDL, Data, or Both).

Comment: I did copy the table from the MySQL Server into the Oracle SQL server.  I was then able to do an INSERT INTO from one table to the other.  However, until we have a task scheduled to load the Oracle table from a newer source, the MySQL server does get updated every day.  Does an INSERT INTO statement work between two different databases (from the MySQL Server to Oracle)?

Comment: only if you have a database gateway configured - this lets you build a DB_LINK between the two databases. You could also license golden gate to replicate changes across auto-magically